# Getting image to center in IE when it does in Chrome and FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have an image that displays when an icon is clicked. The image **SHOULD** center vertically and horizontally, and does so fine in Chrome and FF, but for some reason it fails to get the correct margin sizes in IE. The on click javascript function I have formats the CSS for the image, it will modify the `marginLeft` to half the height, and the `marginTop` to half the width. Below is the code:

```
$('.preview').click(function(){
    var img = $("#<%=imgFull.ClientID%>");
    img.attr("src", $(this).attr('fullImg'));
    img.attr("Visible", "true");

    img.load(function(){
        img.css({
            top: "50%",
            left: "50%",
            marginTop: "-" + (img.width()/2) + "px",
            marginLeft: "-" + (img.height()/2) + "px"
    }, false);
});
    $("#overlay").show();
    $("#overlayContent").show();
});
```

Is there something that I'm missing as far as IE goes? I'm not used to having to cross browser support for it. My former client base was strictly Chrome and FF. The images being tested with are 320x240, so the margins should be

```
margin-top: -160px;
margin-left: -120px;
```

Instead they are

```
margin-top: -14px;
margin-left: -15px;
```

Comment: two questions: 
1// is your site 100% w3c valid. 
2// have you specifically set the img to `display:block`.

Comment: chrome and firefox are really forgiving towards malformed markup, ie is unforgiving.

Comment: @superUntitled The site is in ASP, but tend to stay as close to the w3c standard as I can, in this case I did. As to your second question, no I didn't utilize `display:block`. It didn't seem relevant with the image being placed on top of an overlay.

Comment: I added a more complete answer to your issue, I hope this clarifies things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/img.html#img-display

Images typically will display as inline-block by default, which adds `line-height` into the mix of an elements padding/margin height. Declaring an image to `display:block` in css removes the line-height from the elements computed height.